# Why in some cases in React we use round brackets instead of curly brackets

Tags: reactjs

Here is an example when I saw round brackets instead of curly brackets.

```
export const Navbar: React.FC = () => (
<nav>
<div className="nav-wrapper purple lighten-1 px1">
  <a href="#" className="brand-logo">React + Typescript</a>
</div>
```

)

Comment: It's an implicit return. It's the same as `const NavBar = () => { return (  <nav>..</nav> ) }`

Comment: For the record, this isn't just  a "React" thing. This  functionality is built into javascript, and is called an [Implicit Return](https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/17665/implicit-return).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the round brackets as a "return" where you're saying, "Go ahead and return this" and the curly brackets as a function body where you're saying, "Let me do some additional processing and then I'll tell you what to return."

These two statements are identical:

```js
export const Navbar: React.FC = () => (
  <nav>
    <div className="nav-wrapper purple lighten-1 px1">
      <a href="#" className="brand-logo">React + Typescript</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
)
export const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="nav-wrapper purple lighten-1 px1">
        <a href="#" className="brand-logo">React + Typescript</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

They act the same, but the second one would allow you to add additional code before returning if you needed to do some processing, formatting, or whatever. If you don't, then doing it one way or the other is more a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

1. When if you need return statement

   export const Navbar: React.FC = () => (

   ```
      <>
        {" "}
        // You need to wrap children with parent element
        <nav />
        <div className="nav-wrapper purple lighten-1 px1">
          <a href="#" className="brand-logo">
            React + Typescript
          </a>
        </div>
      </>

    );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Learn ES6 Arrow Functions, You will get this